How to log unhandeld exceptions with Serilog in a ASP.NET MVC Project?
I am using Serilog in a ASP.NET Project with the following code in my Program.cs:
using Alters_Ehejubiläen_Weihnachtsbriefe_Ehrenpatenschaften.Data;
using Alters_Ehejubiläen_Weihnachtsbriefe_Ehrenpatenschaften.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Alters_Ehejubiläen_Weihnachtsbriefe_Ehrenpatenschaften
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString ="";

            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
            try
            {
                //Beispielhafte Integration der Serilog-Protokollierung
                var expr1 = "UserAction is not null";
                var expr2 = "ActionException is not null";

                string env_string = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT").ToLower();
                if (env_string.Equals("development") || env_string.Equals("staging"))
                {
                    connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("WebAppContextStaging");
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .MinimumLevel.Information()
                            .AuditTo.Logger(lc => lc
                                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(expr1)
                                .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connectionString, sinkOptions: new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "UserActionLog", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 1 }))
                            .AuditTo.Logger(lc => lc
                                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(expr2)
                                .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connectionString, sinkOptions: new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "ExceptionLog", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 1 }))
                            .CreateLogger();
                }
                else if (env_string.Equals("production"))
                {

                    connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("WebAppContextProduction");
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .MinimumLevel.Information()
                            .AuditTo.Logger(lc => lc
                                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(expr1)
                                .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connectionString, sinkOptions: new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "UserActionLog", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 1 }))
                            .AuditTo.Logger(lc => lc
                                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(expr2)
                                .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connectionString, sinkOptions: new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "ExceptionLog", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 1 }))
                            .CreateLogger();
                }

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var ex = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
                    using (LogContext.PushProperty("ActionException", "StartupFailure")) { Log.Error("Es ist ein fataler Fehler in der Methode Program.Main aufgetreten: " + ex.Message + ", InnerException: " + ex.InnerException); }
                };
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("ActionException", "StartupFailure")) { Log.Error("Es ist ein fataler Fehler in der Methode Program.Main aufgetreten: " + ex.Message + ", InnerException: " + ex.InnerException); }
            }

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

      
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}

An unhandled Exception (not thrown in try block) gets logged if I throw it in the Programm.cs code. It gets logged in:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    var ex = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("ActionException", "StartupFailure")) {
        Log.Error("Es ist ein fataler Fehler in der Methode Program.Main aufgetreten: " + ex.Message + ", InnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
    }
};

But if I throw an Exception in another class like a controller the exception does not get logged with Serilog. How can I log all exceptions of my application with Serilog without putting everything in try/catch blocks?

It's worth spending some more time reading up on basics such as https://serilog.net - e.g. the Log.Error message should not be composed with +
The question of how to trap errors in ASP.NET is a separate one (and not related to AppDomain,UnhandledException) - have a proper search and you'll find it - once you have that wired up, emitting to the log is the easy bit
